# Show Crystal Reports conditionally

Tags: security, crystal-reports

I want to show crystal reports conditionally. That means if a field value of database table = 'true' than only show reports else do not show reports. I want to protect the crystal reports file from unlicensed users. How can I achieve this in case I do not have the access to the source code?

Comment: Have you integrated Crystal Reports with a custom application (i.e. one where you have the source code) or have you published the report via BusinessObjects Enterprise?  Or another mechanism?

Comment: Yes I have integrated Crystal Reports with VB6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to restrict access to a Crystal Report unless the application that hosts it supports this.  If you have access to its source code, then you can code the desired security.

Otherwise, the best that you will be able to do is restrict the data.  However, this probably uses a license.

I would recommend reading the fine print on your application's documentation to see if viewing reports really does use a CR license.

** edit **

Since you have access to the source code, simply hide/show the UI elements that generate the reports, based on the database-field's value.

Answer (score 2):

If an application level solution is not available, then try creating a SQL Expression Field to get the boolean value from the database table. No put a suppression formula in every section the suppresses the section when the database value is false.

An as a courtesy, you might want to add a section that contains a text element "This report is not licensed" or something similar which is only suppressed when the database value is true. This way users won't think the blank page is in error.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer, however we do somthing similar. We have various clients using our reporting application (done in C# and using CR). Most of our reports are available to all our customers, but there are some customers who have their own reports that are specific to their requirements only and would make no sense to any other customer.

We control this by setting a few properties on the RPT. This is what we do.

1) Right click the xyz.rpt file and go to Advanced tab
2) Set the Keyword property to Customer=123 (This is a unique number for the customer in our databases.)
3) For reports that are Generic, this property is not set and left empty.
4) We have a Reports table in our database with a column named Customer. This is used to check if the report is generic or specific.

I think this wont be of any help, but I just wanted to share. Because this is what we do to hide and show reports using a database value.

Comment: Also this question is for Craig, mate how do I comment on a question like you guys do, without typing in the Your Answer space. Just like you have in your first comment "Have you integrated Crystal Reports with a custom application (i.e........".. I am going crazy and couldnt find it. So had to use the Your Answer space.

Comment: You need to gain reputations to add comment. see here http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation